# How to rejoin scikit-learn Logistic Regression predicted probabilities at same indices?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I've successfully ran a logistic regression on some data that I have using scikit-learn's Logistic Regression and I simply want to get predictions on a dataframe appended to the frame. I have reason to suspect that they predicted probabilities aren't being joined back to the rows that they are meant to be with.

Here is the code where the regression takes place, and where the predictions are appended to the original dataframe.

```
# Split the predictor variables (ind_cols) and the response variable into two sets to feed into logistic regression function.

X = full_sample[ind_cols].to_pandas()

y = full_sample[dep_col].to_pandas()

lm = LogisticRegression(
    fit_intercept=True
)

lm.fit(X, y)

# The DataFrame that I want predictions on is ret_df, and the predictor variables are [ind_cols].

y_pred = lm.predict_proba(ret_df[ind_cols].to_pandas())

y_final = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=['Prob_0', 'Prob_1'])

ret_df_out = pd.merge(ret_df.to_pandas(), y_final, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)

ret_df_out.show()
```

The reason I believe that the values are not being joined to their corresponding rows is because I've done this exact regression in R Studio. Here, when I look at the distribution of predicted values for both positive and negative responses, they are practically the same for the scikit-learn regression.

Is it possible that the predictions are not being joined back to their original rows? It would explain the similarity between the distributions of predicted values for true 0's and true 1's.

Answer (score 0):

Create your final dataframe with the `ret_df` index to ensure indexes be aligned:

```
df1 = ret_df[ind_cols].to_pandas()

y_pred = lm.predict_proba(df1)
y_final = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=['Prob_0', 'Prob_1'], index=df1.index)

ret_df_out = pd.concat([df1, y_final], axis=1)
```